# How to check if PHP field is empty when using SHA1

Tags: php, encryption, sql-update, sha1

I'm using SHA1 to encrypt a password. In my original code I checked if the password fields were empty with: if (empty($newpassword) and (empty($newpassword2))) { }

Since I now use SHA1 and it automatically generates da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709 when field is left blank, how do I re-write my code?

Translate da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709 back to string? Or something else?

Please help.

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        // oude password controle
        if ($password == $qpassword)
            $oudpassword_goed = 1;
        // password controle
        if ($newpassword == $newpassword2)
            $newpassword_goed = 1;
        if (empty($newpassword) and (empty($newpassword2)))
            $newpassword_goed = 2;
        // email controle
        if ($email == $email2)
            $email_goed = 1;
    }
```

Comment: SHA1 isn't recommended for passwords and unsalted hashing is pretty much asking for trouble. Try PBKDF2: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to check if the password field is not empty is use `strlen()` to check the length of the string you're actually sending, so if the string is longer than `0`, then It's not empty, else display an error, telling them that their password field is empty and don't add it to the database. Also, there's no way to convert `SHA1` back to an original string since `SHA1` is a cryptography hashing algorithm, and that would defeat the purpose behind it. Main difference between hashing and encryption is that one can be decrypted and the other one can not. This however doesn't mean `SHA1` hashes can't be brute forced, they are indeed easy targets, as well as `MD5`, but that's for another conversation outside of this scope.

Comment: This "one way encryption method" is not really encryption, it is called hashing.

Answer (score 8):

Just check the input *before* you hash it.

Also, don't use `empty()`. This will tell you the user entered an *empty* password if their password is `0` (of course, you're not allowing passwords of only one character, right?)

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/dm8usSrE).

Comment: It might as well. `0` is not really a password anyway ;-).

Answer (score 2):

You *could* check for `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709` to check if it is empty.

Better though is to check emptiness before hashing.

Comment: What if someone's legitimate password hashes to that too? ;)

Comment: Potentially bad idea to check against the hash. 1) There is a very very very minute possibility another *real* password will collide with this hash. 2) If you ever change your hashing algorithm or salt, you have to remember you hard-coded this value and go back and change it.

Comment: It doesn't. SHA1 conflicts are extremely rare. Besides, then you go back to the first option: check before hashing.

Comment: I can't imagine using a password that accidentally has the same hash as the empty string to be a good idea anyway.

Comment: @alex: The string is a sha1 result of an empty string.

Comment: @BimalPoudel Obviously, but when transforming an infinite number of strings into a sha1, there will be collisions. Perhaps very rare, but something to consider, depending on your application.

Answer (score 1):

The SHA1 hash of `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709` is a well-known hash of an empty string. Check against this value.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like someone forgot to use salt then :-D

Comment: Maybe the person asking the question? :-D
`$pass = 'somestring';
$salt = '}#f4ga~g%7hjg4N';
$hash = sha1($salt.$pass);`

Comment: @sainiuc: Better use a random salt that is unique per password, not only unique per site.